# Why my Bubble Sort code isn´t working properly?

Tags: python

I´m working on a simple bubble sort script. I've tried several test cases, but some of them doesn't order the numbers as expected. Here is my code with one test case that does not work.

```
def bubble_sort(array):

    i = 0
    j = 1

    for x in range(0, len(array)):

        for y in range(1000):

            if(i == 4 and j == 5):

                i, j = 0, 1

            if(array[i] <= array[j]):

                pass

            if(array[i] > array[j]):

                array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]

            #print(array)

            i, j = i + 1, j + 1

            pass

        pass

    return(array)
```

I´m passing this list to the code

> [7, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 10, 15, 2]

And the output is

> [1, 2, 3, 3, 7, 3, 10, 15, 2]

I can´t find the mistake on the code, although I think is in the number and logic of the iterations.
Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Maximum for i and j must depend on array length, not fixed values.

Comment: [Compare to this code to see what you're doing wrong](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-bubble-sort/)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a fixed up version of your code:

I don't understand why your loops use `x` and `y` as enumeration values in the for-loops, but then you use another pair of indices: `i` and `j`. The `i` and `j` don't seem needed.

`if(i == 4 and j == 5)` - not needed.  Is this just a debugging thing?

`pass` is just a no-op.  I don't think you need it.

It's spelled `bubble`, not `buble`

It gets simple pretty fast:

```
def bubble_sort(array):
    for x in range(0, len(array)):
        for y in range(x+1, len(array)):
            if(array[x] > array[y]):
                array[x], array[y] = array[y], array[x]
    return(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is different version of your code.

```
def bubbleSort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n):

        for j in range(0, n-i-1):

            if arr[j] > arr[j+1]:
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]
```

After this codes, you need to initialize(create) your array, then call your def like this; `bubbleSort(arr)` after all this things you can print your array in for loop.

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    print(arr[i])
```